# Whose responsibility is VAT?

Tags: england-and-wales, tax-law

Circumstances:

I have engaged a local building company to quote for works in my home.  He provided a quote of £12k, which included VAT. I called him to haggle the price, and he said that if I paid him in cash, he could reduce the price to £10k “if I didn’t want to pay VAT”. I said that I would be happy to accept a discount, but that the VAT remains his responsibility. We then argued a bit about whose responsibility the payment of VAT is. I took the view that in discounting from £12k to £10k, the price of the underlying job went from £10k to ~£8.3k. He argued that it was up to me whether or not to pay the VAT. We have not agreed on the final price as I am still gathering quotes.

Tangentially i also realise with cash payments, the builder is probably avoiding/evading employers NI also.

It’s frustrating that this is so rife within this industry! I work in financial crime compliance/fraud and would not willingly enter into any sort of tax evasion.

Questions:
Am I correct that the responsibility to apply the correct amount of VAT is with the VAT registered company, in the case of an end customer that is an individual/domestic (ie not another VAT registered company)?

Would I have any liability for evasion in this instance?

Do I have any responsibility to maintain that I paid VAT on this kind of arrangement?

Comment: Also, check the legality of paying the amount in cash. Many countries have laws that limit the amount that can be paid in cash, to make fraud detection easier. And partitioning the payments in several installments would not make it legal; if anything, it would be evidence that it was an attempt to break the law.

Comment: If I was paying someone; especially a builder who does very large "cash-in-hand jobs"; then I would want a solid money trail and proof of purchase. And I certainly wouldn't pay until the job was completely finished. So even excluding the legality aspect of it, there are still other risks that should be considered.

Comment: Is paying cash for such services for such amounts actually legal in the UK?  In some countries it isn't (Italy, Sweden).

Comment: @gerrit, yes it's legal to pay cash, and it may be the only option for some people.  But paying cash _in order to facilitate fraud_ is abetting the crime (sorry, no reference to hand, hence comment rather than answer).  Having a VAT receipt would help defend such a charge.

Comment: Your bank will ask questions when you try to with draw large amounts (over £1K). They are checking that you aren't doing it 'under duress', and if you mention builders, they will ask that you have actually had the work done.  This is just to protect you from fraudsters, and doesn't mean anything, if you reply that it's all OK.

Comment: You asked a builder for a discount and were surprised by the cash/vat answer?

Comment: You misunderstood his comment "if I didn’t want to pay VAT" - He is not saying you need to pay the VAT he is saying "I can you you a discount if you pay me cash because I will not be paying the VAT" - basically it's your choice if you want to help him with his fraudulent tax scheme.

Comment: @SamDean at no point did I say I was surprised; actually, my question indicates the opposite. Thanks.

Comment: @DJ. I did not misunderstand; my point is that my acceptance of the proposed discount does not obviate the vendor’s responsibility WRT the payment of VAT.

Answer (score 16):

The vendor is required to charge and pay VAT, unless exempt for the particular goods or services. [Here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/rates-of-vat-on-different-goods-and-services) is what is exempt: there are a few services exempted, [for instance](https://www.gov.uk/vat-builders/disabled-people)  alterations made to a disabled person’s home. The builder must report the full price and report it, if they are registered. They [must register](https://www.gov.uk/register-for-vat) if total [VAT taxable turnover](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/vat-registration-manual/vatreg02300) for the last 12 months was over £85,000 (total charges minus VAT). A business with less turnover may voluntarily register. The buyer pays what they are charged, it is the responsibility of the vendor to charge the applicable amount.

If the business is required to collect VAT and lies about the transaction, [that is fraud](https://www.lexisnexis.co.uk/legal/guidance/fraudulent-evasion-of-vat), which can be prosecuted. [The law (§72)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1994/23/section/72) says that it is an offense "if any person is knowingly concerned in, or in the taking of steps with a view to, the fraudulent evasion of VAT by him or any other person", and it does not limit fraud prosecution to the vendor. That does not mean that the government *will* necessarily prosecute you, but it sounds like you are aware that this is a fraudulent plan, unless there is some detail missing in the description that makes non-payment (collection) of VAT legal. You basically have an obligation to *not* maintain that you paid VAT.

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive response. I’m not sure I follow your last point about “to not maintain VAT” - I realise in my question I missed the word “records” after the word “maintain”, rather than “maintain” in the sense of “argue”.   If I were to accept the lower quote, I intend to formalise a statement of work with the builder that includes the price of the job (possibly even stating ‘including VAT’) and on completion request a receipt for payment. Do you think that would be reasonable as a defence against evasion?

Comment: @confidenthour The guy is proposing you either pay 12k legally, or 10k as part of a conspiracy to commit tax fraud. If you pick the conspiracy, he's not going to be happy when you then start documenting the fraud and asking for receipts. You can report him to the authorities if you want, but trying to trick him into doing the work at the conspiracy price without abiding by the unwritten rules of the conspiracy (cash only and leave no documentation) is not going to work out well for you.

Comment: @confidenthour You won't get a receipt in the deal they propose.

Comment: @confidenthour I would argue you are currently talking past each other. You want a discount, and you are taking their willingness to do the job under the table as a sign that they are in fact open to giving you a straight-up discount. Nothing in your question indicates that they are.

Comment: From my understanding, a difference between the UK and US is that in many circumstances where a purchase would be exempt from VAT (e.g. a purchase for purposes of export), the seller would be required to collect VAT, but give the buyer paperwork which could be filed to receive a refund of the taxes paid.  If the seller gives the buyer the appropriate paperwork but the buyer never files a refund, the taxes would simply remain paid as required, so the seller wouldn't need to know or care if the buyer was exempt from VAT.

Comment: Sales tax in the US (the closest analog) is mainly but not exclusively a duty imposed on the vendor. There is no "take it away" exception, but there are tax-exempt statuses where e.g. a contractor shows his paperwork at the hardware store and doesn't pay sales tax for supplies that he will then "sell" to a customer – it avoids double-taxation. There are some thing-specific exemptions such as vehicles vs. everything else where sales to non-residents can be exempt.

Comment: To expand on xLeitix's point: The contractor only wants the offer to be intelligible to people who will say yes.  People who say no will potentially reject the contractor as untrustworthy (people who defraud the government might defraud their customers, too).  Or worse, people who say no might report the contractor.  Of course, people who don't understand the offer are probably in the "no" camp, , so now the contractor has reason to be intentionally confusing.

Comment: @xLeitix that’s the point of the question…

Comment: @confidenthour I guess I'm not getting the point of the question. You say you would never willing participate in tax evasion. The contractor proposes tax evasion, and you seem to be fully aware of that. What is there more to discuss than telling them that you don't want to evade taxes, and then moving on, potentially to a better contractor?

Answer (score 0):

Why would it be up to the buyer to decide whether to pay taxes on the purchase?
As far as I can tell, sales tax and VAT are both the seller's responsibility. The buyer just hands a wad of money to the seller, and doesn't have any particular input into where the money goes after they hand it over.

I mean, if you go into a shop and buy something that has VAT on it, you don't know and can't know whether the shop owner actually turns over the correct amount of money to the government, right? Surely the same thing applies here.

Comment: While that logically makes sense what is there to back that up? Also would it change if the buyer knows they are not paying VAT when they should?

Comment: @JoeW: When was the last time you paid VAT in a way that it was not lumped into the payment to the seller? Or, when lumped into said payment, when and how did you verify that the seller correctly paid the VAT they're legally required to?

Comment: @Flater The question states that the seller mentions a discount for not paying VAT which means that they would know that it was not properly paid.

Comment: @JoeW: OP's point is that their knowledge of what the seller may or may not do w.r.t. paying VAT does not somehow transfer the culpability of failing to pay VAT correctly to them (the buyer). The seller is the one who is responsible for paying the correct amount of VAT. In practice, the same would be true even if no discount was discussed: a buyer can never truly confirm if a seller has pocketed their VAT or correctly paid it. It's not the buyer's responsibility to do so and the buyer cannot just take the blame for tax evasion merely by agreeing to a discount.

Comment: In the US, if the buyer doesn't pay sales tax (e.g. on an interstate transaction or if the buyer has a sales tax number), the buyer is still responsible for paying use tax if the state charges one.  VAT is different in that it is an inclusive tax paid by the seller but advertised to the buyer.  There is no equivalent of use tax with VAT.

Comment: Thanks @Flater this is exactly my point. By agreeing to the discount, my view is not that I am evading VAT since the seller must still include it, and the price of job has actually been adjusted proportionally.

Comment: @Darth Pseudonym in principle this is true, and I believe consumer law means that sellers must always include VAT in their prices (or otherwise state ‘excluding VAT’) however the case is different in the respect that seller is stating if I agree to a price, he won’t pay VAT.

Comment: @Flater VAT is always explicitly listed on the receipt.  OP is entitled to a receipt.

Comment: @gerrit: And how does the receipt give the buyer the ability to enforce the seller to pay their taxes (or audit them to see if they have done so or not)? I have many receipts from buying stuff over the years. I have exactly no idea what these companies paid in taxes.

Comment: @Flater You don't, but it should mean the buyer is free from any allegations of facilitating fraud.  And usually, if companies want to evade VAT, they won't want a paper trail.

Comment: @Flater My question was if the buyer knows that the seller is avoiding VAT what does that have on their responsibility. The question is suggesting that the buyer knows that the seller is avoiding VAT by asking a lower price and that likely has an impact on the situation as the buyer knows the seller is breaking the law.

Comment: @JoeW Hearsay. Just because I heard it doesn't mean that that's what they said, intended to say, or meant, nor whethher they followed through afterwards or changed their mind.

Comment: @Flater That is a defense for something and the only reason you would need a defense for it is if you could be held legally accountable. I am not asking if the person would be convicted or what it would take to get them convicted just if they could be held accountable if they knew the seller was not paying VAT and was giving them some sort of deal in regards to that.

Comment: @JoeW: That's your question, but you're not the OP's. The concrete answer here is that the burden of paying the VAT on time does not _transfer_ to the buyer merely by being aware of it. It's possible that they can become an _accomplice_ if they willingly aid and abet the actual process (e.g. paying in Krugerrands in a park at night time, to take an extreme example), but merely by receiving a discount and paying in a legal way is not enough to warrant criminal activity (I'm assuming here that they're not going to participate in avoiding any cash transfer limits that need to be reported)

Comment: @Flater It was part of the question and it should be addressed in the answer as well. If the answer is suggesting that the buyer is at no risk when they know that the seller is not paying VAT on a purchase and the buyer can be risk that does not make for a good answer. The question specifically asks if they have any liability in this case